# Array column contains values of other array column

Tags: arrays, h2

How can I ask for an array column having all values of another array column?

```sql
DROP TABLE A IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE A(foo INT ARRAY, bar INT ARRAY);
INSERT INTO A(foo, bar) VALUES
  (ARRAY[1, 2, 3], ARRAY[1, 2]), 
  (ARRAY[2, 3], ARRAY[1, 2, 3]);
SELECT foo FROM A WHERE foo <contains all values of bar>;
// [1, 2, 3]
```

If I could get the distinct values of an array I could do something like this:

```sql
WHERE DISTINCT(foo || bar) = foo
```

since if concatenating foo and bar doesn't add more values, the values of bar must already be in foo.

Problem seems that I can't use the various functions UNIQUE, DISTINCT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS etc since they work on the array value as a whole while I need to compare the values inside. I have tried using TABLE, UNNEST and looked in the h2 project tests for clues, all without luck.

EDIT 1: Seems related to the problems described in this thread:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1815

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see from the [`UNNEST` function](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#unnest), it creates a new scope each time it's invoked, causing the outer scopes to be inaccessible.

From the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255217/discussion-between-vonc-and-marc-grue), any attempts to use `UNNEST` or `TABLE` ends up with an error.

And [`array_to_string`](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/test/org/h2/test/scripts/functions/string/array-to-string.sql) only works with static values.

---

A possible alternative would be to consider a Java-based solution, where you can handle these operations in a more flexible environment. You can create a custom Java function and then call this function from your H2 query.

- Write a Java method that accepts two Integer arrays as parameters, iterates over all elements in the second array to check if all of them are present in the first array, and returns a boolean indicating whether this is true.
- Compile the Java method and make it accessible to the H2 database.
- Register the Java method as a stored function in the H2 database.
- Call the Java stored function in your SQL query to perform the desired array comparison.

The Java method would look like:

```java
public static boolean doesArrayContainAll(Integer[] array1, Integer[] array2) {
    if (array1 == null || array2 == null) return false;
    return Arrays.asList(array1).containsAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
}
```

To register the Java method in H2, you would use a statement like:

```sql
CREATE ALIAS DoesArrayContainAll FOR "path.to.your.Class.doesArrayContainAll";
```

You can then use this method in your query:

```sql
SELECT foo
FROM A
WHERE DoesArrayContainAll(foo, bar);
```

Comment: Thanks @vonc. Unfortunately I get "Column "T1.BAR" not found;"

Comment: @MarcGrue OK. I have rewritten the query with more aliases.

Comment: Unfortunately generates the same error.

Comment: @MarcGrue OK, let's try with an IN or a JOIN. The goal is to avoid any scoping issue.

Comment: Latest version gives "Column "A.BAR" not found;" It seems like we can't get access to A.bar inside an unnest this way.

Comment: SELECT fooElement FROM UNNEST(A.foo) generates "Column "A.FOO" not found;"

Comment: @MarcGrue I have added another JOIN approach

Comment: Unfortunately this also generates "Column "A1.BAR" not found;"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255217/discussion-between-vonc-and-marc-grue).